# Align abstract horizontally to the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, abstract, text

I redefined an abstract environment in order to center it in the page. I want to keep that but aling the text to the left instead of to the center but I'm not managing to do it. Any suggestions?

Here's my code so far:

```
\newenvironment{abstract} %
{\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}\textbf{Abstract\\}\ignorespaces}
{\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}\cleardoublepage}
```

Edit: I managed to justify it using:

```
\begin{justify}\textbf{Abstract\\}\ignorespaces}
{\end{justify}
```

The problem now is that also the title "Abstract" is aligned to the left but I want to center it

Comment: `abstract` is a predefined environment so at first you should use `\renewenvironment` instead of `\newenvironment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If got you right, you want yout abstract to be horizontally justified, vertically centered, and the title "Abstract" horizontally centered. In this case, there is no need for `center` Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newenvironment{MyAbstract}{%
    \cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \hfil\textbf{Abstract}\hfil%
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces%
}{
    \vspace*{\fill}\cleardoublepage
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{MyAbstract}
        \blindtext
    \end{MyAbstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AndreaCRD If it suits your needs, please mark the answer as a solution.